# Cannot bind to properties of an object that implements ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

To explain my case, let's consider a simple object like this:

```
public class FixedSeries : Series
{
    int val1, val2;
    public FixedSeries(int val1, int val2) { this.val1 = val1; this.val2 = val2; }
    public int Diff
    {
        get { return val2 - val1; }
        set { val2 = val1 + value; }
    }
}
```

Then, if in my form I want to bind `Diff` to a control's value I can do:

```
BindingSource source;
FixedSeries fixedSeries;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    fixedSeries = new FixedSeries(2, 5);    
    source = new BindingSource();
    source.DataSource = fixedSeries;

    numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Value", source, "Diff", false, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
}
```

However, if my `FixedSeries` derive from a more generic `Series` (see here below) that implements the `ICollection<int>` interface I get an `ArgumentException` "Cannot bind to the property or column `Diff` on the DataSource".

```
public class FixedSeries : Series
{
    public FixedSeries(int val1, int val2)
    {
        base.Add(val1);
        base.Add(val2);
    }
    public int Diff
    {
        get { return base[1] - base[0]; }
        set { base[1] = base[0] + value; }
    }
}

public interface ISeries : ICollection<int>
{
    int this[int index] { get; }
}
public class Series : ISeries
{
    List<int> vals = new List<int>();
    public int this[int index] 
    { 
        get { return vals[index]; } 
        internal set { vals[index] = value; } 
    }
    public void Add(int item) { vals.Add(item); }
    public void Clear() { vals.Clear(); }
    public bool Contains(int item) { return vals.Contains(item); }
    public void CopyTo(int[] array, int arrayIndex) { vals.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex); }
    public int Count { get { return vals.Count; } }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
    public bool Remove(int item) { return vals.Remove(item); }
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() { return vals.GetEnumerator(); }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return vals.GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

I guess this has something to do with the `ICollection<T>` interface and maybe to the fact that .NET expects to bind to items inside. How can I bind to the `Diff` property in this scenario without removing still the possibilities to bind to items inside the series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess this has something to do with the ICollection<T> interface and maybe to the fact that .NET expects to bind to items inside.

Correct. More precisely the `IEnumerable<T>` which `ICollection<T>` inherits.

> How can I bind to the Diff property in this scenario without removing still the possibilities to bind to items inside the series?

Here are some options

(A) Do not use the `BindingSource`, bind directly to the data source object

```
numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add("Value", fixedSeries, "Diff", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

(B) Wrap the data source object into a single item array/list and use that as `BindingSource.DataSource`

```
source.DataSource = new[] { fixedSeries };
```

(C) Similar to (B), but use `BindingSource.Add` method (w/o supplying `DataSource` property at all)

```
source.Add(fixedSeries);
```

Comment: Taking the simplified example I provided, all the solutions work. If I take my original files solution (A) fails. Maybe some other flaw, but no time now to search for it, just wanted to tell for possible interested people